# Loop changes button binding functions

Tags: python, for-loop, button, kivy, kivy-language

```
    sair_grid = self.root.ids["sairler_screen"].ids["sair_grid"]

    for a in dler:
        with open(a,"r",encoding="utf-8") as file1:
            for b in file1:
                btn = Button(text=b[:-5],on_press=lambda y:self.sairi(b))
                sair_grid.add_widget(btn)



def sairi(self,x):
    pass
```

No matter which button I clicked to calling the function, it is giving the same result. I want every button to take different b values and call the function with different arguments. All buttons created with different names but each of them calls with same last argument of the file. I am new in python and kivy so every help is really appreciated.

Comment: This is a common gotcha.  See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result).

Answer (score 0):

There is only one variable named `b` here and it changes its value until the last one remains last time the loop executes:

```
for b in file1:
    btn = Button(text=b[:-5],on_press=lambda y:self.sairi(b))
    sair_grid.add_widget(btn)
```

So, you are creating many lambdas, but they all use the same `b` from the closure.

A typical simple workaround for that problem is to bind the current value of b to a default value of the lambda argument:

```
for b in file1:
    btn = Button(text=b[:-5],on_press=lambda y, b=b:self.sairi(b))
    sair_grid.add_widget(btn)
```

Now each lambda you create has a locally bound `b` argument which has its own default value. The default value of `b` is now different for each lambda you create.

Comment: I think you could also do it using `partial` as `on_press=partial(self.sairi, b)`.

Comment: [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is the other common fix for this.

Comment: Thank you very much! I I've been looking at this for three days...